# Decorrelating Systems of Random Variables

Tags: correlation, lasso, causality, partial-correlation

Suppose we have a dataset that includes dozens of attributes, that are all correlated with each-other. I would like to better understand which variables affect which other variables in a causal way, preferably as a system of regressions. The classical approach would be to setup a structured model, identifying manually which attributes are endogenous and exogenous. However, in my situation this seems hopeless because it's hard to attribute which attributes are correlated causally vs, through other hidden variables.

I was hoping to get some advice on alternative approaches to this problem. I've heard about partial correlation analysis with adaptive lasso that tries to select and isolate effects of attributes on each-other, assuming conditional independence on the rest. Are there any other approaches as well? What are some other popular techniques?